# Extract URL from text file - Python

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to extract a URL from a text file which contains a source code of a website. I want to get the website link inside href and I wrote some code I borrowed from stackoverflow but I can't get it to work.

```
with open(sourcecode.txt) as f:
    urls = f.readlines()

urls = ([s.strip('\n') for s in urls ]) 

print(url)
```

Comment: It also give an error source is not defined

Comment: You should probably have a look at HTML parsing libraries like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Answer (score 3):

Using a regexp, you can extract all urls from the text file, without the need to loop line by line:

```
import re
with open('/home/username/Downloads/Stack_Overflow.html') as f:
    urls = f.read()
    links = re.findall('"((http)s?://.*?)"', urls)
for url in links:
    print(url[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for this.

```
import re

with open('sourcecode.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

href_regex = r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)'
urls = re.findall(href_regex, text)

print(urls)
```

You're probably getting an error like `'sourcecode' is not defined`; this is because the parameter that you pass to `open()` needs to be a string (see above)

Comment: NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: re is the regular expression module, it's part of the standard library. `import re`